# MySQL Replication Master push to Slave

Tags: mysql

I have two servers that need to be synced. One is online and has a public IP address. The other is internal and has no public IP address - nor is there a way to get it a public IP so that's off the table.

I'd like to set up replication between the two servers through MySQL but as I understand it, the MySQL slave needs to be able to connect to the master (i.e. the master doesn't just simply push data out) and that's a problem since there's no public IP or interface to connect to.

Is there any way to replicate and simply tell the master to push data to the slave (which it can access)? Alternatively, is there some other solution? I have considered a mysqldump periodically but the data is going to grow very quickly resulting in too-large dump files.

Comment: just dump changes.  etl and partitioning are your friends here.

Comment: If both are on the same network you should be able to use internal ips even if only one is configured with a public.

Comment: The answer you are looking for maybe found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722659/online-offline-database-synchronization-mysql-php

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are able to connect to Remote MySQL server (Online server) from a Slave server machine.
You can verify by using `telnet` command

`# telnet <online server IP><space><MySQL port>`

Now follow the replication procedures mentioned here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html

For Database synchronization refer existing answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946540/how-do-i-sync-2-mysql-databases

Answer (score -1):

At first, create OpenVPN Server on your online database server.

Then, connect from your internal database server to your online database server.

Now, your database server should be able to PING each other, and can be set to use normal replication as it should.